# Callback from an app to the previously opened tab in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have a payment web page which opens a payment app on an Android device.
When the payment is done, the app makes a callback to my web page but the callback opens the web page in a new tab.
I want it to open it in the already open tab. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I currently have the same issue.